# Exception in "_openGLControl.InitializeContexts();" line

Tags: c#, opengl, tao-framework

I have an exception {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."} during the debuging a "_openGLControl.InitializeContexts();" line. (Tao.Framework)

But the same project works fine on another computer. And I don't understand what to do. I already tried to reinstall Tao.Framework, but it is didn't help. May be somebody else had this problem?

Comment: Just Graphic Card drivers need to be reinstalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Graphic Card drivers need to be reinstalled.